# We are (called) the Smiths

Tags: person-names

How does one pluralize a family name?

- Wir heißen den Smiths? der Smithen?
- Wir sind die Smith Familie?

Which of these is most natural, and which are acceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you pluralize a family name in German with an "s":

> Wir sind die Schmidts.

But your proposals also are in principle okay, albeit lightly to correct:

> Wir heißen Schmidt.
>   Wir sind Familie Schmidt.

Comment: It is somewhat surprising for non-native speakers that the *default* plural inflection for things that aren't really nouns is "-s", when almost no normal German words form an "-s" plural, but it's nevertheless true. Language is fun!

Comment: +1. You can also find these two options reflected in the German titles of American sitcoms. E.g. _The Jeffersons_ became _Die Jeffersons_, and _The Flintstones_ became _Die Familie Feuerstein_.

Comment: @KilianFoth: I assume, that this is exactly the reason for the -s plural. One has not necessarily an idea, which language the name derives from and which declination to apply, therefore one opts for a generic/international scheme.